# Correctly Sizing a Canvas inside a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe, java-2d

my current project is a small desktop application in Java that functions like a room decorator similar to the IKEA software that lets you plan out your room before you go and buy furniture. When I thought about that concept my mind immediately jumped to the RTS Genre of games. Thinking about WC3 and StarCraft experiences I had my thought was to implement a basic grid interface where i can just place down squares as a starter demonstration type of deal.
I understand scaling a Canvas (java.awt.Canvas) inside a basic JFrame is .. weird since the Frame itself consumes space for its outer border display. So it converted the 1600/900 Frame width/height to 1584/861 Canvas width/height.
What I want is to be able to divide the display into a grid of 5x5 squares but, as you might immediately recognize, neither 1584 nor 861 is cleanly divisible by 5.
I fumbled a bit with Modulo ( % ) and quickly ran out of ideas so I turned to the internet for help yet google and stackoverflow was suprisingly void of information about the ratio at which jframes steal away size from its inner components.

My question now would be, is there any efficient method to tell the frame to wrap itself around a canvas of a certain size rather than taking the space it needs from it? or any other mechanic i can use to arrange a Canvas to a certain size disregarding the space the frame needs? Because just trial and error on fumbling together the right frame size for this to work seems to me like an ugly solution that only works for the specific case of 5x5 squares.

Comment: There is nothing weird about scaling the coordinates used during painting.  Scaling is independent of the Canvas size.  That’s kind of the point of scaling.  Graphics2D coordinates are floats, so you don’t need to worry about the dimensions being evenly divisible by 5.

Comment: Instead of a Canvas, use a JPanel as a drawing panel.  You can set the preferred size of the drawing panel and let the JFrame pack the drawing panel and any other control panels.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html

Comment: @VGR I'm not talking about the scaling of coordinates, i'm talking about the phenomenon of when you set the size of a jframe to 1600x900 and a panel, canvas or whatever you have of the same size inside the inner component will natively lose in dimension due to the frame consuming some of that space in order to display its outer borders

Comment: Rather than targeting a specific size (which would break on any system whose video mode is smaller than 1600×900 anyway), maximize the frame and draw on whatever size your canvas happens to be.